# How to optimize Jenkins workspaces for branches

Tags: git, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, branch

We have a c++ project that is revision controlled in GIT. We use Jenkins as our CI, and as we have a relatively large number of branches in our system we encounter some issues with build time. As some of the branches contain changes in a base class interface, the whole project is being rebuilt when switching from one branch to another. Usually, a developer doesn't need to switch often - but two developers may work on two different branches with different interfaces - and it make the life hard for the Jenkins build.

As I understand it, there are two options to configure the workspaces: shared workspace set for all branches, or different workspace for every branch. While the latter option is too expensive in disk space and the need to reclone for every branch, the former option makes the Jenkins rebuild on every push.

I would like a third option: all branches share the same workspaces set but with prioritization: If a branched used a certain workspace in the near past, then we would like it to use it again (to reduce build time) - if there is no workspace that the branch was the last to use, then the CI would use a workspace that was the least recently used. This way we would not blow up the disk usage and get more decent performance.

The question is - are there tools/plugins existing in Jenkins that can allow having the abovementioned logic of using workspaces? Is it possible to develop such logic in Jenkins via plugin or groovy script?

Answer (score 0):

Using a shared library step you can implement the kind of logic you ask for determining a workspace directory. However, as not all branches need to be built all the time, I highly recommend you do use your second suggestion: you can use the [multi-branch plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-multibranch) and configure it to filter branches according to a pattern. This way merged branches should be deleted to preserve space (you can also rename them or remove their `Jenkinsfile`.)

If you still want to make your own workspace allocation mechanism you will have to know how to enumerate them, how to keep each directory exclusive to a certain run and how to re-use them. Sooner or later you'll find out it's not worth your time and that you would better invest in re-using artifacts from previous builds of your branches rather than the whole build itself, so there's your 4th choice :)